# how to @autowire dao class created in project A to the rest controller class in Project B

Tags: spring, rest, maven

I created a Springboot application with dao class, model and rest controller. it works fine.

now i want to create rest controller in separate project.

Project A : model + dao class
Project B: rest controller

in Project B pom.xml I included the Project A jar file under dependency

Now i m trying to autowire dao class from project A to the restcontroller class in Project B.

In the rest controller class (project B) i used @ComponentScan(basePackages="package where my  daoclass is there")

But i am getting compilation error saying cannot resolve the symbol for the line daoclass dao;

I am new to spring and springboot. Not sure what is wrong.. please help me to understand it better

I am trying to do mvn clean package (project B)

Answer (score 0):

You need to register the class as a bean in the spring context with the **applicationContext.xml** for projectB, otherwise projectB can't find the bean created by projectA.

For example, you should write following **applicationContext.xml**

```
<context:component-scan base-package="name.space.for.projectA"/>
```

You can also configure component-scan with annotations:

[18. Using the @SpringBootApplication annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html)

- (a) Specify target packages as `scanBasePackages`
  `@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"name.space.for.projectA"})`

or

- (b) Specify target packages as `@ComponentScan`

`@SpringBootApplication 
 @ComponentScan("name.space.for.projectA")`

Answer (score 0):

**Check your jar file exists in local repository.**

Open your local repository folder in setting files

```
<localRepository>Your Directory</localRepository>
```

And check your jar file is in there.

If file is not exist, try copy and paste it first.

And if Project B is Okay, then check your maven setting file.

Answer (score 0):

Maven will always look in your local repository (usually found in `~/.m2/repository`) for dependent jars.

Therefore you must execute:

```
mvn clean install
```

in projectA. This will copy your projectA-version.jar into your local repository, where projectB will be able to find it.